# Creating a data.frame for R package

Tags: r, r-package

I am making an R package, and there is a need to keep track of files that were opened using the functions in the package.

What is the recommended procedure for creating R objects (in this case, a data.frame) upon loading the package in a way that is (sufficiently) hidden from the user? I do not want the user to manually edit the data.frame.

One idea I had was to create a data.frame in the `options` settings inside of an `.onLoad` call (similar to what Hadley does in his `devtools` package [here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/zzz.r)), but the list of opened files is not really a configurable "option" in my package. Is there another way?

Comment: When you set up the package you have to list the objects to export, right? Can you just leave the data frame out of that list?

Comment: @AlexA. Such a simple and brilliant idea. I think that will work - let me give that a whirl

Comment: @AlexA. I think your comment pointed me in the right direction. I am now having some trouble with the scope (i.e. changes not persisting after modifying the initialized data.frame). You can write your comment as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: I'm very glad I could help you on the right track but I'm sorry to hear it didn't get you all the way. I worry that the scoping issues are because the data frame isn't exported... :\

Comment: I like `devtools::use_data(..., internal = TRUE)`.  This creates sysdata.rda  in the R file, and is thereby executed when the package is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an R package, unless you're exporting all objects, you have to list which objects are exported in the NAMESPACE file. If you need to maintain a data frame within your package but you don't want it made available to the user, you can choose not to export it by excluding it from the list.